# Update Fields in one table if fields in another are not equal

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have one table of customer information - `[Customer Alignments]` that is the master table.

As things process, there is another table that compiles customer information at the point of helping the customer. This is called `[tCC Master]`

So, what I would like to do is take this `[tCC Master]` table and check to see if the information in the `[Customer Number]` and `[Therapy]` fields differ from the `[Customer Alignments]`. If they do, I want to update these fields to display the new `[Customer Number]` and/or `[Therapy]` from `[tCC Master]`

i.e.:

```
[Customer Alignments]

 - Number - Therapy - Location Number
 - 1 - ABC - 1234
 - 2 - BCD - 5678
 - 3 - YES - 9101
 - 4 - ABC - 0246

[tCC Master]

 - Number - Therapy - Location
 - 1 - BCD - 1234
 - 5 - QWE - 5678
 - 3 - YES - 9101
 - 6 - ABC - 0246
```

This is what I have, but I'm not sure about it

```
UPDATE [dbo].[ru_t_Customer Alignments]

SET [dbo].[ru_t_Customer Alignments].[Customer Number] = [dbo].[ru_tCC_Master].[Customer Number] (@[dbo].[ru_t_Customer Alignments].[Customer Number], [dbo].[ru_t_Customer Alignments].[Customer Number])
     , [dbo].[ru_t_Customer Alignments].[Therapy] = [dbo].[ru_tCC_Master].[Therapy] (@[dbo].[ru_t_Customer Alignments].[Therapy], [dbo].[ru_t_Customer Alignments].[Therapy])

FROM [dbo].[ru_t_Customer Alignments], [dbo].[ru_tCC_Master]

WHERE [dbo].[ru_t_Customer Alignments].[Customer Number] <> [dbo].[ru_tCC_Master].[Customer Number] OR [dbo].[ru_t_Customer Alignments].[Therapy] = [dbo].[ru_tCC_Master].[Therapy];
```

If someone could help point me to a solution, that would be wonderful. 
Thank you!

Comment: What is the natural key here? Location?

Comment: [Customer Number] should be PK on both tables? How would you join two tables? Why do you want update [Customer Number] on master table?

Comment: We have been going through post-acquisition changes that are stirring things up. 

Location would be something that wouldn't change, but there could be dependencies between the therapy and number. There are other fields like location name, district, etc... These would all remain relatively static.

Answer (score 0):

First you should bind two table.  Then update that columns if data is different.
I assume that location info newer differ in these tables and they are unique for all customer.

I also gave short aliases to tables to make it easy to understand.

```
UPDATE  CA

SET     CA.[Customer Number] = CM.[Customer Number], 
        CA.[Therapy] = CM.[Therapy] 

FROM    [dbo].[ru_t_Customer Alignments] CA
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[ru_tCC_Master] CM ON CA.[Location Number] = CM.[Location]

WHERE   CA.[Customer Number] <> CM.[Customer Number] 
        OR CA.[Therapy] <> CM.[Therapy] ;
```